# Can Single JMSTemplate be shared in multiple producers?

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-integration, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I want to share the single instance of JMSTemplate for multiple producers connecting to ActiveMQ broker. Sample config:

```
<bean id="ProducerJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
 <property name="connectionFactory">
     <ref bean="gloProducerJmsFactory" />
 </property>
</bean>

<bean id="pnlMessageProducer1" class="glo.business.core.FAGSCompletionMessage1"
 p:jmsTemplate-ref="ProducerJmsTemplate"
 p:messageDestination-ref="topic_loadGearTb1"
</bean>

<bean id="pnlMessageProducer2" class="glo.business.core.FAGSCompletionMessage2"
p:jmsTemplate-ref="ProducerJmsTemplate" 
p:messageDestination-ref="topic_loadGearTb2"
</bean>
```

Can I use above configuration ?

As mentioned here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

*Instances of the JmsTemplate class are thread-safe once configured. This is important because it means that you can configure a single instance of a JmsTemplate and then safely inject this shared reference into multiple collaborators. To be clear, the JmsTemplate is stateful, in that it maintains a reference to a ConnectionFactory, but this state is not conversational state.*

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 3):

Yes...

> ...you can configure a single instance of a JmsTemplate and then safely inject this shared reference into multiple collaborators...

... is exactly what your configuration does.